# how to subtract one path from another?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

So... I have a base path and a new path.New path contains in it base path. I need to see what is different in new path. Like we had /home/ and new path is /home/apple/one and I need to get from it apple/one. note - when I would create some path from (homePath/diffPath) I need to get that /home/apple/one again. How to do such thing with Boost FileSystem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using stem() and parent_path() and walk backwards from the new path until we get back to base path, this works, but I am not sure if it is very safe.
Be cautious, as the path "/home" and "/home/" are treated as different paths. The below only works if base path is /home (without trailing slash) and new path is guaranteed to be below base path in the directory tree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main(void)
{
  namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

  fs::path basepath("/home");
  fs::path newpath("/home/apple/one");
  fs::path diffpath;

  fs::path tmppath = newpath;
  while(tmppath != basepath) {
    diffpath = tmppath.stem() / diffpath;
    tmppath = tmppath.parent_path();
  }

  std::cout << "basepath: " << basepath << std::endl;
  std::cout << "newpath: " << newpath << std::endl;
  std::cout << "diffpath: " << diffpath << std::endl;
  std::cout << "basepath/diffpath: " << basepath/diffpath << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `while(tmppath != basepath)` using `while(!fs::equivalent(tmppath,basepath))` is more robust.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem; // or boost::filesystem

fs::path base = "/home/usera"
fs::path full = "/home/usera/documents/doc"
```

If you want to extract `documents/doc`, you can do that with [`lexically_relative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal):

```
fs::path diff = full.lexically_relative(base);
assert( diff == fs::path("documents/doc") );
```

This works for `base = "/home/usera"` or `base = "home/usera/"`.  If `full` does not contain `base`, this may give you a pretty long path with lots of `..` instead of getting an error.

`std::filesystem::path::lexically_relative` requires C++17

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, if you know that `newpath` really belongs to `basepath`, could be:

```
auto nit = newpath.begin();

for (auto bit = basepath.begin(); bit != basepath.end(); ++bit, ++nit)
    ;

fs::path = path(nit, newpath.end());
```