# How to build a full path string (safely) from separate strings?

Tags: c++, qt, filepath

Does C++ have any equivalent to python's function `os.path.join`? Basically, I'm looking for something that combines two (or more) parts of a file path so that you don't have to worry about making sure the two parts fit together perfectly. If it's in Qt, that would be cool too.

Basically I spent an hour debugging some code and at least part of it was because `root + filename` had to be `root/ + filename`, and I'm looking to avoid that in the future.

Comment: Possibly distantly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772992/get-relative-path-from-two-absolute-paths (specifically, related to _that_ question is boost's `complete`)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check out [QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#filePath) for that:

```
QString path = QDir(dirPath).filePath(fileName);
```

Comment: Beware that Qt is GPL. Might be a deal breaker for many uses.

Comment: @RustyX it is LGPL, to be precise.

Comment: i love this answer, no futzing with strings and concatenation, let the framework figure it out.

Answer (score 116):

Only as part of [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) library. Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main ()
{
    fs::path dir ("/tmp");
    fs::path file ("foo.txt");
    fs::path full_path = dir / file;
    std::cout << full_path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of compiling and running (platform specific):

```bash
$ g++ ./test.cpp -o test -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
$ ./test 
/tmp/foo.txt
```

Comment: This is also in TR2, which is likely to start shipping with compilers next year.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for the permalink! I was always wondering if it exists.

Comment: @Vlad : Yeah, it's not easily discoverable, but I hate clicking on Boost doc links and belatedly realizing I'm looking at an old version, so I edit people's version-specific links when I come across them. :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: Which seems to work great now... but wait until they change something about the site or the docs for the given library.  It is worse than leaving the version-specific link from then on.

Comment: @Fred : From what I remember, policy was put in place when 1.35 was released to prevent that from ever happening.

Comment: @ildjarn: Filesystem is already on v3, do you expect to stop there? Changes to the docs mean blindly re-editing to auto-updating links will be confusing (different parameters, name changes from the text in the answer, etc.), even if the links lead to a non-404 page. Filesystem v2 was the default for 1.44 and 1.45, so Filesystem has *already* undergone doc changes (after 1.35 that you mention) that could be very confusing for an answer written when those were the current versions.

Comment: @Fred : Obviously if the functionality or question happens to be version-specific, I don't change the URL. In this case, it isn't, so I did.

Comment: @ildjarn: How do you predict what a given library will change in the future so you can know if all the answers you edit will make sense for all future versions?

Comment: @Fred : Are you implying that at some point in the future, Boost.FileSystem might lose the ability to do what the OP is asking for? Really? In general, the answer to your question is "I use my brain." So far that seems to have worked out just fine.

Comment: With C++17 use `#include <filesystem>`, `namespace fs = std::filesystem;`. With C++14 use `#include <experimental/filesystem>`, `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;`.

Comment: Never say only – if other answers are correct, Boost is not the only solution.

Answer (score 69):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297807) (but not using `boost`), this functionality is available as part of [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append). The following code compiles using Homebrew GCC `9.2.0_1` and using the flag `--std=c++17`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() 
{
    fs::path dir ("/tmp");
    fs::path file ("foo.txt");
    fs::path full_path = dir / file;
    std::cout << full_path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As of C++17, this was merged into the (non-experimental) <filesystem> header. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is a way to go in case if c++ 17 is available on the project.

Comment: in my case its just joining them directly (and not putting a `/` or ```\``` between them)

Comment: @0xB00B just use  `A + B`,  `fs::path` override the operator `/` /  `+` to append/concat. see reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/concat

Comment: @Kevin Chan i was already talking about that,  it wasn't working properly due to some implementation bug.

Answer (score 10):

At least in Unix / Linux, it's always safe to join parts of a path by `/`, even if some parts of the path already end in `/`, i.e. `root/path` is equivalent to `root//path`.

In this case, all you really need is to join things on `/`. That said, I agree with other answers that `boost::filesystem` is a good choice if it is available to you because it supports multiple platforms.

Comment: QT is agnostic to path separator. If you print absolute path of a file on Windows the output is "C:/Users/Name/MyFile.txt" with the / (unix) separator. boost::filesystem is great but, in my opinion, if the project is Qt-based there's no need to add a dependecy for boost library.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this with Qt, you can use `QFileInfo` constructor:

```
QFileInfo fi( QDir("/tmp"), "file" );
QString path = fi.absoluteFilePath();
```

Answer (score 5):

With C++11 and Qt you can do this:

```
QString join(const QString& v) {
    return v;
}

template<typename... Args>
QString join(const QString& first, Args... args) {
    return QDir(first).filePath(join(args...));
}
```

Usage:

```
QString path = join("/tmp", "dir", "file"); // /tmp/dir/file
```

Answer (score 4):

In Qt, just use `/` in code when using Qt API (`QFile`, `QFileInfo`). It will do the right thing on all platforms. If you have to pass a path to a non-Qt function, or want to format it for displaying it to the user, use `QDir:toNativeSeparators()` e.g.:

```
QDir::toNativeSeparators( path );
```

It will replace `/` by the native equivalent (i.e. `\` on Windows). The other direction is done via `QDir::fromNativeSeparators()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple **C++11** friendly alternative for the people who have neither Boost, Qt nor C++17 (taken from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch10s18.html)).

```
std::string pathJoin(const std::string& p1, const std::string& p2)
{
    char sep = '/';
    std::string tmp = p1;

#ifdef _WIN32
    sep = '\\';
#endif

    // Add separator if it is not included in the first path:
    if (p1[p1.length() - 1] != sep) {
        tmp += sep;
        return tmp + p2;
    } else {
        return p1 + p2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test the code? It should be `p1[p1.length() - 1] != sep` instead of `p1[p1.length()] != sep`. We may also consider that Windows accepts both `'\\'` and `'/'`

Comment: @Rotem: Thank you for pointing out, I fixed the length problem in my answer.