# Qt - C++ string concatenation segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, string-concatenation

I'm new to c++, so I guess I fell into a newbyes C++ pitfall.

I tried to do the following:

```
QString  sdkInstallationDirectory=getenv("somEnv");

QString someSourceDir=sdkInstallationDirectory+"\\Data\\"+someReference+ "\\src";
```

and I get a segmentation fault.

I guess this is because of the concatenation of the const chars and insufficient memory allocated to the `someSourceDir` QString.

What exactly is my mistake? How can I do this concatenation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

It appears that I was wrong, and the segmentation fault was caused a line before, where I created the reference I mentioned in the question.

I discovered it with further debugging.

Sorry for the confusion, and thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

```
char * getenv ( const char * name );
```

> A null-terminated string with the value of the requested environment
>   variable, or **NULL if that environment variable does not exist**.

Why you not check result?

**EDIT.**

So, check pointer is not necessary.

> For historical reasons, QString distinguishes between a null string
>   and an empty string. A null string is a string that is initialized
>   using QString's default constructor or by passing (const char *)0 to
>   the constructor.

Comment: Well, the tool is installed by installer that creates the environment variable. No variable=no tool, I will check it as precaution of course, but it is not the cause. Anyway - great answer, and +1. I found the problem, and it was not related for the question, sorry.

Comment: QString can handle a Null-Pointer construction, the constructor QString(const char*) will create an empty QString with Unicode coding. The code provided by sara is perfectly fine and clear.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add strings together with a +. Try using a stringstream.

Something like:

`stringstream ss;

ss << sdkInstallationDirectory << "\Data\" + someReference << "\src";

string str = ss.str();`

Although, if you are using Qt, you shouldn't be joining paths as strings.

See [How to build a full path string (safely) from separate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297738/how-to-build-a-full-path-string-safely-from-separate-strings)

Comment: Doh. Yeah, that would work too, so you have to make sure that all the strings above are QStrings. `QString("\Data\") + QString(someReference)` etc.

Comment: QString has + operator so it would work. Except that if you got a null pointer, it crashes...

Comment: @LKM : not necessarily, look at the prototypes in his link. Moreover, pobjects can be constructed on the flight by compiler to fit.