# How to split a path into separate strings?

Tags: c++, boost, path, split, cross-platform

This is a complimentary question to:
[How to build a full path string (safely) from separate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6297738/1798187)

So my question, how to split a path into separate strings in a cross platform manner.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297807/1798187), using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) is very elegant and Boost must have implemented some splitPath() function. I couldn't find any.

Note:
bear in mind that I can do this task myself but I'm more interested in a closed box solution.

Comment: Are you looking to split all parts of the path, or just the parent directory from the filename?

Comment: @idanshmu : can you please give some sample i/p's and o/p's?

Comment: Have you look at [path::iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-iterators) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, there is `path_iterator`. But if you want elegance:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
    for(auto& part : boost::filesystem::path("/tmp/foo.txt"))
        std::cout << part << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
"/"
"tmp"
"foo.txt"
```

And

```
    for(auto& part : boost::filesystem::path("/tmp/foo.txt"))
        std::cout << part.c_str() << "\n";
```

prints

```
/
tmp
foo.txt
```

No need to worry about the moving parts

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<std::string> SplitPath(const boost::filesystem::path &src) {
    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    for (const auto &p : src) {
        elements.emplace_back(p.filename());
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was still typing and compiling the sample while this answer was being posted.

Comment: If `elements` has type `vector<string>` you should write `elements.emplace_back(p.filename().string())`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have C++11 auto, or are writing cross-platform code where boost::filesystem::path might be std::wstring:

```
std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> elements;
for (boost::filesystem::path::iterator it(filename.begin()), it_end(filename.end()); it != it_end; ++it) 
{
    elements.push_back(it->filename());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do everything manually without, using any library, then this will help.
It splits the given full path into corresponding names and store them in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filePath = "C:\\ProgramData\\Users\\CodeUncode\\Documents";
    vector<string> directories;
    size_t position=0, currentPosition=0;
    
    while(currentPosition != -1)
    {
        currentPosition = filePath.find_first_of('\\', position);
        directories.push_back(filePath.substr(position,currentPosition-position));
        position = currentPosition+1;
    }
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = directories.begin(); it!=directories.end(); it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:
ProgramData
Users
CodeUncode
Documents
```

Comment: You have posted the same (poor) code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69426192/10871073). Best not to post 'duplicate' answers to multiple questions ... consider deleting one answer and improving the other.