# The os.path equivalent in C++ without Qt?

Tags: c++, command-line, filesystems, os.path

I need to set a directory and then read all the filenames of the files inside and store the whole path in a variable. I need to use this this variable later , to open the file and read it. I don't want use `QDir` for this. I saw the second answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297738/how-to-build-a-full-path-string-safely-from-separate-strings). I can use `boost/filesystem.hpp` (I believe this need not be downloaded separately). But the problem is execution will look like this:

```
$ g++ -o test test.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
$ ./test
```

My first line, for creating executable object is already complicated due to OpenCV libraries and I don't want to add to it. I want to keep them simple (the following line plus whatever OpenCV wants):

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

**Is there any way to do it?**

This is the python code for which I want to write C++ code:

```
root_dir = 'abc'
img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir,'subimages')

img_files = os.listdir(img_dir)
for files in img_files:
    img_name = os.path.join (img_dir,files)
    img = cv2.imread(img_name)
```

Comment: Avoid naming `test`  your executable. It is a standard POSIX program `/bin/test`  or a shell builtin. Call your test binary `mytest`

Comment: Why don't simply use cv::glob?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I copied `test` from the other question, in the link. I just continued to use it for the rest of the question.

Comment: @Miki Thank you for the suggestion. Looks like I might be able get my job done with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choices are to use boost, QDir, roll your own, or use a newer compiler which has adopted some of the TR2 features that are staged for C++17. Below is a sample which roughly should iterate over files in a system agnostic manner with the C++17 feature.

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
...
fs::directory_iterator end_iter;
fs::path subdir = fs::dir("abc") / fs::dir("subimages");
std::vector<std::string> files;

for (fs::directory_iterator dir_iter(subdir); dir_iter != end_iter; dir_iter++) {
  if (fs::is_regular_file(dir_iter->status())) {
    files.insert(*dir_iter);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I will go with boost and create a file that contains everything that should be called while creating the object. What do you think of that?

Comment: Sounds like the most reliable approach. In a few years there will be less need to carry such a large bundle into small problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux or POSIX ....

You might use low-level [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) or [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc... Of course you'll need to deal with dirty details (skipping `.` & `..`  entries, assembling the file path from the entry and the directory path, handling errors, etc...). You might also need [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).
You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) to get a broader view.

For other OSes (notably Windows) you need other low-level functions.

BTW, you could look into the source code of Qt for `QDir`

You could consider also using [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/)